# How do i join my profile table to my friend of friend query?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a query to get a user's friends of friends (FOF). The query works perfectly for retrieving the FOF from the table, however, I need to join the FOF profile table in order to gain access to the useful information regarding said FOF.
My tables:

```
profile
userId | a bunch of other data

request
receiver | sender | status
```

Both receiver and sender correspond to userId within the profile table. A status of 1 means the users are confirmed friends

Here is my current query which works for retrieving the FOFs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender 
FROM request
WHERE receiver IN (
    SELECT sender 
    FROM request 
    WHERE receiver= ${theuser} AND status = 1) 
    AND sender NOT IN (
        SELECT sender 
        FROM request 
        WHERE receiver=${theuser} AND status=1) AND sender<>${theuser};
```

Ive tried a number of different JOINs, with a JOIN statement being included in the 1st, 2nd and/or 3rd SELECT statements including the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sender 
FROM request
LEFT JOIN profile on userId = sender
WHERE receiver IN (
    SELECT sender 
    FROM request 
    WHERE eceiver= 2 AND status=1) 
    AND sender NOT IN (
        SELECT sender 
        FROM request 
        WHERE receiver=2 AND status=1) AND sender<>2;
```

Unfortunately it is not joining the profile table. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: and what is the problem with the last query?

Comment: It returns the FOF without joining to the profile table

Comment: queries only return, which columns you have in a select, so you only return senders, add all columns that you need to the first select `SELECT sender, profile.name,....`

Comment: ugh how did I miss that!?! lol. thanks!